# Getting undefined even though variable is declared in TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular app with a block of code where I want to push values to an array.

Even though I declared a variable 'contactWithInitials' I'm getting an error saying 'Cannot read propery push of undefined'.

What am I missing here?

```
    let initialHold: any;
    let contactWithInitials: any [];

    this.contacts.forEach( eachObj => {
      if(eachObj.first_name){
        initialHold = eachObj.first_name.charAt(0);
      }
      if(eachObj.last_name){
        initialHold += eachObj.last_name.charAt(0);
      }

      contactWithInitials.push({'userInitials':initialHold});

    })
```

Comment: Don't use `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared what type contactWithInitials is, but you didn't actually set it...

```
let contactWithInitials: any[] = [];

// or if you want to have a stronger type
let contactWithInitials: { 'userInitials': string }[] = []
```